# Views Slideshow alternating blank screens with content items

Tags: views

Views Slideshow with JQuery Cycle had been working successfully for a long time, displaying a cycling set of 8 photos with cross-dissolve transitions. Now it's displaying a blank screen between each content item, for the same duration specified for those items in Views>Slideshow>Settings. All content is being displayed, nothing skipped, and transition is correct. But it acts as if a blank item is alternating with the intended content. I tried going back to earlier versions of Views and JQuery but there was no improvement in this problem.

Suggestions on why this might happen and how to fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem disappeared when I disabled the module "devel_themer." I began to suspect it only after looking at the dynamic code in Firebug, which showed the images trying to cycle and to cross-dissolve by animating transparency. I saw a lot of modified code referring to this module name, and figured that since it's not the native code that should be seen here, it would be worth trying the disable and see what happens. Problem apparently solved.